# jquery easywidgets after drop widget then their style changing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to use jquery easywidgets plugin, 
When i tried to drag and drop on the any widgets, divs style changing, especially texts are pixelerate.
you can also see on the pictures.

Before drag

[alt text http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/5116/beforedrag.png](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/5116/beforedrag.png)

After drag

[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/5844/afterdrag.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/5844/afterdrag.png)

What can i do for solving that problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a live site with an example of this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response.
You check here http://bb.magudas.com/jq/easywidgets/examples/1/ with an internet explorer instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you place a background-color on the containing div that fixes the issue (or did for me)

Comment: I will try as soon as posible and then i will update to you. Thank you for your response and time.